# Converting input string into rest link javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm developing a search mechanism with REST requests.

There is an input form, that accepts product titles:
`Macbook Pro`
`iPhone-6`
`Jack's iPad`

I need to send those titles to server in rest format (as a part of a link), such as:
`Macbook+Pro`
`iPhone???6`
`Jack???s-iPad`
Is there a library or a way to do this conversion using javascript? (*I can't use json)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you wish to communicate search terms to a REST service?

Assuming your example of `Macbook+Pro` did not indicate a search operator, you just need to encode your parameters so that the values properly embed into a URL.

For example [https://www.google.nl/search?q=These are search arguments](https://www.google.nl/search?q=These%20are%20search%20arguments) will become *https://www.google.nl/search?q=These%20are%20search%20arguments*.

That, or you do a POST which contains a body (an example is a `<form>` submit with `<input>` controls).

Encoding example using plain javascript ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqehm93w/)):

```
var searchTerms = 'Macbook Pro';
var searchTermsEncoded = encodeURIComponent(searchTerms);
var url = 'https://www.google.nl/search?q=' + searchTermsEncoded;
console.debug(url); // https://www.google.nl/search?q=Macbook%20Pro
```

Similarly, `Jack's iPad` becomes `Jack%27s+iPad`.

Depending on the type of back-end you are using, your server will decode for you or you have to do it manually. Either way you end up with the original input strings as typed by the user.